# What limitations are there to creating a Bitcoin client on Google App Engine?

Tags: client, bitcoind, development, bitcoin-core

I want to create a Bitcoin client on App Engine with equivalent protocol functionality to bitcoind.

With the new Sockets API available in [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/) and [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) I believe this would *almost* be possible.

The only hurdle I see is that other clients would not be able to broadcast their new transactions to the App Engine client as the Sockets API does not support listen sockets. The App Engine client would have to continually poll other clients to check for new transactions and blocks.

Are there any more App Engine limitations which would get in the way of creating a client with identical protocol functionality to the bitcoind standard client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run Bitcoin on Google App Engine? / alternatives?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/is-it-possible-to-run-bitcoin-on-google-app-engine-alternatives)

Comment: @NeilNeyman this question is similar but not the same. I am not asking if it is possible to use App Engine as a bitcoin client, because I know it is. I am asking how close to bitcoind can you get with the sandbox restrictions enforced by App Engine. The only limitation I can think of is as mentioned in my question. Are there any more?

Comment: I see, ok sorry. Probably worth leaving this question there as a sort-of follow-up.